# Eager Loading disabled by Custom Extension

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a database table called `Accounts` and there's a column `isCustomer`.
To make my `/Entity/Customer.php` only return accounts that are actual customers I used a [Custom Doctrine ORM Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/)

There is also a relation with the `Contacts` table. I'd like to add Contacts to Customer when the `/customers` URL is requested. This relation exists and is working properly, and is also eager loading.

The moment I created the `/Doctrine/CustomerExtension.php` the result set only consists of customer accounts (with contacts), like I expected.
But at the same time the Eager Loading ORM Extension doesn't work anymore.
All relations are lazy loaded now even with `@ORM\ManyToOne(fetch="EAGER")` on every relationship.

How do I add  `$queryBuilder->andWhere('isCustomer = 1');` by default AND keep eager loading?

- My first attempt has been to add `normalizationContext={ "groups": {"boost"} }` to `/Entity/Customer.php` and put all the properties in that group. It didn't fix eager loading :(

Comment: It is not clear what is problem. Do you want fetch related association when request parent entity? https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that I have a relation with Contacts that used to be eager loaded and now suddenly isn't anymore